# Flask and Nginx: css not recognized

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, nginx, flask

I am trying to deploy my website using Flask. Everything is working perfectly locally (localhost:5000), but when I deploy it on my distant **linux ubuntu server** ([www.linode.com](http://www.linode.com)) I encouter a problem. I have installed **gunicorn** and **nginx**, but **my CSS files are not taken into account**, thus, my webpage just appears as an HTML content alone, without shape/colors and so on.

I am very new at web development, and I don't understand why it works perfectly locally and not anymore (not totally) on the linux server. Is the problem related to the nginx that can't manage to do the **link between HTML and CSS**? Because locally I don't need to use nginx, and everything works.

Here is my nginx config file for when I type *sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/assets*:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 45.79.250.111;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    location /static {
            alias /home/gardy/ladybird_site/assets/static;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
            proxy_redirect off;
}
```

}

And here is my website directory tree:

```
ladybird_site/
requirements.txt
run.py
assets/
    __init__.py
    config.py
    models.py
    fonts/
        et-line.eot
        ...
        fontawesome-webfont.woff2
    main/
        routes.py
        __init__.py
    templates/
        index.html
        layout.html
    static/
        css/
            animate.css
            bootstrap.min.css
            font-awesome.min.css
            style.css
            bxslider/
                jquery.bxslider.css
                images/
                    bx_loader.gif
                    controls.png
            et-line-font/
                style.css
            magnific-popup/
                magnific-popup.css
            owl-carousel/
                owl.carousel.css
                owl.theme.css
                owl.transitions.css
        images/
            ldb_ico.ico
            founder_pics/
                custom_pics/
                    f1.jpg
                    f2.jpg
                    f3.jpg
            ldb_imgs/
                1.png
                2.png
                3.png
        js/
            bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js
            bootstrap.min.js
            ...
            jquery.bxslider.min.js
            main.js
```

I am getting crazy with that stuff, trying and modifying things since two days without significant improvments, and found no answers on the internet...

Thanks a lot

Comment: Seems like a permission error. What permissions do you see when you run `ls -la /home/gardy/ladybird_site/assets/static`? Directories should be 755 ("drwxr-xr-x") and files should be 644 ("-rw-r--r--").

Comment: @christian Thanks a lot for your answer, I have created a new answer to my post for a better lisibility

Answer (score 0):

Your static path looks fine. You have set your server to listen to port 80, which is the default port for HTTP, but maybe you have not opened it. The next step is for you to open it.

```py
sudo ufw allow http/tcp
```

You mention that your server is still listening to port 5000. However, if you are done with testing, you can disallow this port from being used by Nginx.

```py
sudo ufw delete allow 5000
```

Enable these new rules by running the command below:

```py
sudo ufw enable
# Hit 'y' for 'yes' when prompted
```

Finally, you can now restart your Nginx server:

```py
sudo systemctl status nginx.service
```

If you navigate to your application's IP address, and append `static/css/style.css`, you should be able to access your CSS file. I mean `http://<your IP address>/static/css/style.css`